# URL formating using htaccess dynamically

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have user profile pages with urls like

```
http://xxxxx.com/trainer-profile.php?id=MTAy&mrkr=LnBuZw==
```

I want to change the URL FORMAT like

```
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile/John-Michael/
```

Already updated the **htacess** code and removed **.php** extension from the URL.

But i need the url format like

```
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile/John-Michael/ 
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile/Will-Smith/
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile/Michael/
```

The users are adding dynamically and now i have over 100 users already registered. Searched in stackoverflow and find out the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(bill/.+)$ /shop/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/bill/?$ /shop/bill/home.php [L,NC]
```

Is it possible to format the url like above dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^trainer-profile/([^/]+?)/?$ /trainer-profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

But id will be the name used in the link !

With:

```
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile/John-Michael/
```

The redirection:

```
http://xxxxxxx.com/trainer-profile.php?id=John-Michael
```

You have to change ID code use in your PHP page

Comment: The `/trainer-profile.php` page don't show, or with error ?

Comment: Trainer profile page shows, but failed in getting the id. so no details for the user shows

Comment: Like I said in my answer, id is the link name, in your first link you show an other kind of ID, it's not possible to use this url id, if it's not in the link...